# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setExtraStackFrame')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently facing the issue mentioned below.
Tried many changes to fix it but didn't get a perfect solution for this.

```
    at setCurrentlyValidatingElement (react-jsx-runtime.development.jss:574:1)
    at checkPropTypes (react-jsx-runtime.development.jss:618:1)
    at validatePropTypes (react-jsx-runtime.development.jss:1072:1)
    at jsxWithValidation (react-jsx-runtime.development.jss:1192:1)
    at jsxWithValidationDynamic (react-jsx-runtime.development.jss:1209:1)
    at MyComponent.render (MyComponent.jss:85:35)
    at Ho (935.js:2:72533)
    at Qo (935.js:2:72332)
    at Hu (935.js:2:113091)
    at Pi (935.js:2:99309) {componentStack: '\n    at MyComponent (http://localhost:800…://localhost:8000/777.js:1:17479)\n    at Suspense'}
```

`MyComponent.jss:85` has a different component from a module which is throwing method error, when tried removing the component the error vanishes, but the component is needed. I tried with matching the common versions of dependencies. It throws same error.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { SidePanel } from '@carbon/ibm-products'
import '@carbon/ibm-products/scss/index-without-carbon.scss'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      error: {}
    }
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    this.setState({
      error: ''
    })
    
  }
  render () {
    const { onSubmit, isOpen, onClose } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <SidePanel
          className='test'
          onRequestClose={() => onClose()}
          title='Title'
          actions={[
            {
              label: 'ok',
              onClick: () => onSubmit(),
              kind: 'primary'
            },
            {
              label: 'cancel',
              onClick: () => onClose(),
              kind: 'secondary'
            }
          ]}
        >
          Hello INSIDE SIDE
        </SidePanel> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

MyComponent.displayName = 'MyComponent'

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  isOpen: PropTypes.bool,
  onClose: PropTypes.func,
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func
}
export default MyComponent
```

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: Take a look at this issue on the React github repo. You might be using the production react scripts and bundling with NODE_ENV != production
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20359

Comment: How do I use development react scripts with NODE_ENV != production. I mean when I do react-scripts start?

Answer (score 1):

I also had the "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setExtraStackFrame')"
Adding a key to the map solved my problem. This solution was purposed my ahmetcaglayan.
[Here is  the link to his answer](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20359#issuecomment-1177480160)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the previously installed packages listed below:

1. React
2. React-Dom
3. types@react-dom (in case of typescript)

After removing install the latest version of the above packages.
The problem will be fixed.